# How to draw grid around irregularly arranged web elements?

Tags: html, css, border

I need to do the following with my HTML with CSS:

I need to enclose some HTML in a big box.

Within the big box, I need to have two smaller boxes, Box I and Box II.  Box I and Box II should both have the same height as the big box.  Box I should be 75% of the width of the big box and Box II should be 25% of the width of the big box.

The big box should have a border around it, and there should be a border seperating Box I and Box II.

So far, what I have described is basically a big rectangle with two partitions.

Next, within Box I, there should be three boxes, Box IA, Box IB, and Box IC.  These three boxes should take up the full width of Box I, and each should be 33% of the height of Box I.  There should be a border seperating the three boxes.

In other words, I have a big box with four partitions; How can I draw a grid to partition them?

What I've tried so far is using an HTML div for each box.  I see the CSS border property to give each box a border.  However, the boxes are still seperated from one another, resulting in a jumble of borders.

```
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
    .contentbox {
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width:thin;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='bigBox'>
    <div id='boxI' style='width:75%'>
        <div id='boxIA' class='contentbox' style='height:33%'></div>
        <div id='boxIB' class='contentbox' style='height:33%'></div>
        <div id='boxIC' class='contentbox' style='height:33%'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='boxII' class='contentbox' style='width:25%'>
    </div>            
</div>
</body>
```

It should look like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
|                                   |                   |
|      box IA                       |                   |
|                                   |                   |
|                                   |                   |
+-----------------------------------+     box II        |
|                                   |                   |
|      box IB                       |                   |
|                                   |                   |
|                                   |                   |
+-----------------------------------+                   |
|                                   |                   |
|                                   |                   |
|      box IC                       |                   |
|                                   |                   |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should draw a diagram of what you want

Comment: Your examples doesn't quite illustrate the problem. Try posting it on jsfiddle.net and dropping the URL into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing fine but:

give both boxI and boxII `float:left`

next drop border on boxII because it moves it to next line because:

boxI(75%) + boxII(25%) + boxII-border-left(1px) + boxII-border-right(1px) are more than 100% of parent box

Use background color for debugging.

So for borders:

boxII give it `border-left: 1px...`, and `margin-left: -1px`

boxIA should have **no border**

boxIB and boxIC should have `border-top: 1px...` and `margin-top: -1px`

Tested in FF, Chrome, IE7 and IE8

Here is full solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/JawC6/3/

Comment: I looked at the example you posted on jsfiddle.net.  It is close.  However, I see that there is a 1 px border between Box I and Box II.  There is a 1 px border between Box IA, Box IB, and Box IC.  I'm guessing that you have two 1px borders side by side.

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions for this:

1. Only give the individual boxes the borders they need (for example `boxIA` and `boxIB` only need a bottom border);
2. Use negative margins to pull boxes up and to the left so they overlap slightly (1px);
3. Use css settings like `display: table-cell` to let the boxes behave like a table (haven´t tried that one yet with borders...). This leads to (older...) browser compatibility problems.

Personally I would just use option 1 as all boxes have an id anyway but I guess option 3 is the most scalable.